# Spring Session Redis with Sticky session on server side for log

Tags: redis, websphere, load-balancing, jedis, sticky-session

Hi i have a Redis configured on my Spring project to use Spring Session, i'm using Jedis 2.9.0 and it works well. The problem I have is with the Sticky session on the Websphere Server, we have 2 main servers and 10 clones of each, with normal httpSession it uses the cookie to handle the request of that cookie to the same server again, good, but with Spring Session it doesn't work the same.

Spring create the cookie with the name "SESSION" and the Load Balancing of Websphere doesn't know where to redirect the request because the session is not on the JVM but is ditributed in Redis Cluster.

i need to (for log order porpuse) handle every request of cookie "abc123" to the server 1 clon 3 for example, and if that instance of the application goes down track that cookie to another instance and stay on that instance until the server goes down again or the user logout...

Searching here and the Spring Session doc, i found something that might be useful but I dont know how it works.

```
@Bean
public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID"); 
    serializer.setCookiePath("/"); 
    serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$"); 
    serializer.setJvmRoute("123");
    return serializer;
}
```

The atribute Jvm Route adds a suffix to the cookie to know whats the JVM that handle that cookie, but i don't know how it works and I haven't been lucky finding examples or explanation about it.

if anyone have the answer or another workaround that i could use it will be great.